# CSS Parallax effect: How do I transform only the background of a section?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I managed to create a CSS parallax effect for the background of a section, making it scroll slower than its surroundings. 
To be more precise, it adds a translateZ to the entire section, which is overlapped by all other sections.

And here's my problem with that: I don't want the entire section to scroll slower than the rest, I only want the background image to do that. The heading over it should scroll normally.

How can I add the parallax effect on the background image while all other elements of the section remain without any scroll effect?

Here's a snipped of what I mean:

```css
.wrap {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    perspective: 2px;
}

.section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #fff;
    height: 50vh;
}

.section-content {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 0 15px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.parallax {
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    z-index: 90;
}

.background {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 80;
}

.background-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.section .background img {
    width: 100%;
    top: -50vh;
    z-index: 90;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

    <div class="section section-md">
        <div class="section-content">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" section parallax">
        <div class="background ">
            <div class="background-image">
                <img src="http://story-teller-photography.de/upload/outland/convert/c857a6dc02e0e048a12d91f58cbeec39_1800_0.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section-content">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="section-content">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <div class="section-content">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Since your parallax class wraps your heading, the heading will scroll.  If you adjust your parallaxing CSS to be `.section .background.parallax` and move the parallax class into your `class="background"` div, I think that will fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

try adding "parallax" class to "background" and not to "section".

```css
.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  perspective: 2px;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #fff;
  height: 50vh;
}

.section-content {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.parallax {
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index: 90;
}

.background {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 80;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.section .background img {
  width: 100%;
  top: -50vh;
  z-index: 90;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="section section-md">
    <div class="section-content">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" section ">
    <div class="background parallax">
      <div class="background-image ">
        <img src="http://story-teller-photography.de/upload/outland/convert/c857a6dc02e0e048a12d91f58cbeec39_1800_0.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-content">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="section-content">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="section-content">
      Hello World
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Already tried that. It works for Chrome, but not for any other browsers. Check it in Firefox, the background scrolls normally, overlapping the top section.

Comment: Removing position: relative for section worked. Not sure that would help you or not.

Comment: If I remove position:relative, z-index will no longer work, making it impossible to prevent the background image from overlapping other sections